# Conditional rendering

Tags: react-native

Помогите с решением?

Есть массив, в котором массив может динамически меняться на объект. Вот пример api:

```
"images":{"small":null,"big":null}
```

а может меняться на объект:

```
"images":{"small":[{"src":"\/upload\/resize_cache\/iblock\/1a5\/150_150_0\/1a5579d1a11b26448d19543a1d35d367.png","width":150,"height":127,"size":37603}]
```

как в это случае сделать render? Вот код:

```
 <View style={styles.vidItems1}>
              {renderIf(item.images.small === null,
              <View></View>
              )}
              {renderIf(item.images.small > 'null',
              <View>
                  {item.images.small.slice(0, 1).map((subitem) => 
                  <ImageBackground key={subitem.src}
                    source={ require('./images/no_car_1200.png') }
                    style={{ width: 120, height: 93, borderRadius: 3 }}
                    fadeDuration={0} >
                  <LazyloadImage host="lazy-list" 
                    // defaultSource={require('./images/NightKing.jpg')}
                    source={{ uri: subitem.src }}
                    style={{ width: 120, height: 93, borderRadius: 3 }} 
                    />
                    </ImageBackground>

                )}
                </View>
              )}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не использовать всякие renderIf, а нормально записать условный или логический оператор:

```
<View style={styles.vidItems1}>
  <View>
    {item.images.small &&
      (Array.isArray(item.images.small) ? item.images.small : [item.images.small]).map(x => (
         <ImageBackground key={x.src} source={require('./images/no_car_1200.png')} style={{ width: 120, height: 93, borderRadius: 3 }} fadeDuration={0}>
           <LazyloadImage host="lazy-list" source={{ uri: subitem.src }} style={{ width: 120, height: 93, borderRadius: 3 }} />
         </ImageBackground>
        )
      )
    }
  </View>
</View>
```